# Git difftool directory with bcompare

Tags: linux, git, redhat

I defined my git config with `git config --global diff.tool bc3`

When I do `git difftool --dir-diff`, a becompare windows opens but I can't compare local file to remote.

- On left panel, I see all remote files containing a difference with local files.
- On right panel, I see theses file but only as shortcut to local file.

I can't compare a file to a shortcut. Is there a way to configure git or becompare to compare all files local to remote ?

Comment: Which 2 revisions do you want to compare? Try `git difftool --dir-diff rev1 rev2`.

Comment: I want to compare my local files against the develop branch (my base branch)

Comment: What's your OS ? windows ?

Comment: @LeGEC I'm workong on Linux RedHat 6.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git difftool --dir-diff` will always create these symlinks when you compare something to your worktree.

---

There seems to be a specific setting for symlinks in Beyond Compare's menu :

https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?sessiondirhandling.html

- under : Session > Session Settings > Handling
- there should be a section : File Handling
- with a checkbox : Follow symbolic links

Try checking that box.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, Thank you.